# Magento store switcher shows empty field for a particular store

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, switcher

[image]

As seen in the screenshot above, the store switcher showes an empty row for a particular website.

I've checked stores config and it is fine there.

Also checked core_website, core_store and core_group in the database and the information is ok there.

Tried deleting the website and recreating it, same issue. Tried reindexing, cache.

My question, what is the **table in the database** from where the store switcher grabs the info? Maybe if I edit the db manually it will solve it. Or anything else that I can try.

Comment: Try to find a translation for the store name.  May be someone has changed "your store name" to "" with "translate inline" feature or with a CSV file.

Comment: @Amasty ahh good shout, thanks. you can submit as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find a translation for the actual store name. May be someone has changed

"your store name" to ""

using `translate inline` feature or with a CSV file